# How can I use Activity Manager to request alerts/notifications/etc via ADB?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I am working on a project where I need to provision a large batch of phones (Samsung S7/S7 Edge, unrooted, no SIM, if that's relevant) for use in the GearVR at a semi-public event. I need to disable any and all alerts/toasts/notifications/etc so that our application is not interrupted while the experience is running.

I believe I have already determined all the required settings and services I need to configure/disable, and have been able to automate applying these settings via ADB. I now need some way to test that they are actually doing what I want.

I think the way to do this is by using Activity Manager to launch various intents, but after reading through the AM and Intent docs I'm still confused on how to do this, or if it's even possible.

A basic example of AM control from ADB is something like this:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "http://developer.android.com"
```

How could I leverage Activity Manager to do things like:

- Raise an alert dialog with an arbitrary string, or ask the system to show me some kind of dialog from an existing app with the right manifest permissions?
- Raise a toast/heads up/alarm/etc with an arbitrary string, or request a toast/heads up/alarm/etc from some existing system application or setting?

Am I even on the right path? I've tried exploring service calls, but that only left me more confused.